# Remote Desktop keyboard shortcuts within another Remote Desktop session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I am accessing my desktop work machine through remote desktop. Inside this remote desktop session I am starting a remote desktop session to a windows server.

But the usual remote desktop shortcut keys:

(i.e. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>end</kbd> for desktop equivalent to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>)

is working only on my desktop machine, even if I have the remote server session full screen.

Is there a way I can use the shortcut keys on the server session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I have read the key combination for the nested RDP session should be:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>

It doesn't work for me from home, but it is likely a permission/version problem for me. Your mileage may vary.

---

**EDIT**

The correct combination is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>

Comment: Nice. Please do feel free to share if you have a link to resources describing shortcut keys in nested Remote Desktop sessions.