# How to Toggle Full-Screen Mode in Remote Desktop Inside Another Remote Desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Desktop keyboard shortcuts within another Remote Desktop session](https://superuser.com/questions/323366/remote-desktop-keyboard-shortcuts-within-another-remote-desktop-session)

In my VPS, I ran remote desktop and connected to another VPS. Now, the new remote system has the entire screen and I can not control the main VPS!

How can I toggle full-screen mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what your desktop looks like.  But if the problem is that one remote desktop bar at the top is covering up another, that's easily fixed.  You should be able to slide it to the side to reveal the bar for the other session.

Here's what it looks like with one bar over another at the top of the screen when you RDP into one machine and from there to a second machine:
[image: One RDP bar hiding the other]

And here's what it looks like when you slide the top bar to side, revealing the one underneath:
[image: Sliding one RDP bar to the side to reveal the other]

If you don't see the bar, it's possible you have it set to float, rather than pinned to the top of the screen.  Move your mouse to the top and it should reappear.  You can toggle it between pinned and floating by clicking on the button at the left end of the bar.

Comment: thanks for the answer, where is that bar? how can i reveal it? i still have that problem!

Comment: I've added pictures showing the RDP bars you should see at the top of the screen.  Hope this helps.