# Remote desktop connection dos not respond anymore (no more task bar)

Tags: remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Desktop keyboard shortcuts within another Remote Desktop session](https://superuser.com/questions/323366/remote-desktop-keyboard-shortcuts-within-another-remote-desktop-session)

I have a remote desktop connection (from my home) to the company's server. On this I opened a Remote Desktop Connection Manager and inside this connect to a specific server.

I was busy copying a file but this task never ends. So I kill the process and now I have a blue screen and no more taskbar. Very frustrating. When I try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> (=<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>) this is executed on the main server and not the server which gives me the blue screen. I don't know if I'm clear.

I know I should have keep Task Manager open and type `explorer.exe` into the **File**->**Run** but I close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Ctrl + Shift + Esc" and hope the "frozen" server answer.

Comment: No problem. Ctrl+Shift+Esc invokes the Task Manager directly. Always.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to reboot the host using psexec

http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html

```
psexec \\targetIp cmd -u username -p password

shutdown -r
```

then just keep pinging it until it comes back up. then attempt to reestablish your connection.